# WHERE doesn't recognize and INSERT throws unique exception

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I read some of the answers here and get "mind-locked".  I am new and don't work at this, just taught myself over the last 43 years.  I converted a piece of code from the hit counter I wrote the other day, and it simply counts the number of times an IP runs my denied access page.  The code checks to see if the IP is already in the database table (unique).  If it is, it simply increments and updates.  If it isn't there, it inserts it with a value of 1.

All was well, then I noticed no increment when testing.  So I isolated it and found that it won't recognize the table column value to update it, and it throws an exception when it tries to insert it as a new value because it is unique.

I have looked and looked and cannot seem to understand why it works fine in my hitcounter, but fails miserably here?!?

```
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$IP = preg_replace('#[^0-9\.]#','',$IP);
$db_table = 'deniedcounter';
echo 'Enter denied_record.php<br />';
//$IP = str_replace('.','x',$IP);

function setdeniedcounter($IP, $db_handle, $db_table){
    $hits = null;
    $ip = "'".$IP."'";
    try{
        echo "SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE ip = $ip".'<br />';
        $stmt = $db_handle->query("SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE ip = $ip");
        $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
        echo $row_count.' = Rows selected.<br />';
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        db_exception_handler($e);
    }
    if($row_count == 1){
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $row['ip'].' '.$row['hits'].'<br />';
        $hits = $row['hits']; $ip = $row['ip'];
        $hits++;
        try{
            $stmt = $db_handle->prepare("UPDATE $db_table SET hits=? WHERE ip=?");
            $stmt->execute(array($hits, $ip));
            $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
            echo $affected_rows.'<br />';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            db_exception_handler($e);
        }
        exit();
    }
    elseif($row_count == 0){
        $hits = 1;
        try{
            $stmt = $db_handle->prepare($sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(ip, hits) VALUES(?, ?)");
            $stmt->execute(array($ip, $hits));
            $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
            //echo $affected_rows.'<br />';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            db_exception_handler($e);
        }
    }
    //echo 'Hits = '.$hits.'<br />';
    if(isset($hits)){return $hits;}
}    

$db_handle = db_OPEN($db_host, $db_name, $db_username, $db_pwd);
if(strlen($IP) > 6){$da_hits = setdeniedcounter($IP, $db_handle, $db_table);}
if(!isset($da_hits)){$da_hits = setdeniedcounter('ALERT', $db_handle, $db_table);}
$db_handle = db_CLOSE($db_handle);
echo 'Exit denied_record.php<br />';
exit();
```

====================
OUTPUT:

```
Enter denied_record.php

SELECT * FROM deniedcounter WHERE ip = '127.0.0.1'

0 = Rows selected.

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry ''127.0.0.1'' 
for key 'ip'

Exit denied_record.php
```

Comment: You should use prepared statements for your `SELECT` as well. Also, "just taught myself over the last 43 years" ??

Comment: What @Svish said. The problem could be because you are trying to insert `'ip'` instead of `ip` in the prepared statements section.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php look @ 2nd example, maybe this will help. And : "PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object."

Comment: Besides the single quotes, a misunderstanding of rowCount was also affecting the results.  Thanks ... learned a bit from that one.  I started programming 43 years ago.  I am finally playing with server side and browser scripting languages.  My website is over 20 years old now, and until a few weeks ago, the pages were all written in HTML from about that long ago ... hehe.  I have had so much fun revamping it.  Never realized how far scripting had come and how nice it is to have a built in human interface as the backbone.  I always had problems with the human interface.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql has a special operator for you.
No need for SELECT first - just INSERT with some extra code:

INSERT INTO $db_table(ip, hits) VALUES(?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+1

So, your function actually have to be

```
function setdeniedcounter($ip, $db_handle, $db_table) {
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO $db_table(ip, hits) VALUES(?, 1) 
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+1";
    $stmt = $db_handle->prepare();
    $stmt->execute(array($ip));
}
```

bu if you want hits returned - you need to select them though

Comment: This won't help him because he has put the single quotes into his $ip variable. He's not checking/using the right value for a prepared statement.

Comment: I finally got it to work with preparing and binding properly, without the query, and the row count was an improper use as described by on of the other posters. Now I will try the code above.  That would make everything soooo much easier.  Good to have Your Common Sense!  Worked like a charm ... so elegant.  Thank you.  And I did get it working using namespaces and not using the single quotes and with preparing and binding properly.

Comment: @Your Common Sense - Well Colonel, I looked all over to find a place to send a private thank you.  Couldn't find one. THANK YOU ... just knowing about conditional SQL statements has made life easier.

Comment: I am not real colonel to be strict. Just a pen name. Glad you liked it. I am always after not only fixing code but also to make it concise but readable. So, every my work aimed to it. And I like when it helps other people. So, thank YOU for you valued my humble efforts

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're checking two differnt things. When you use the prepared statement question mark, MySQL inserts its own single quote. So what you check initially is if 127.0.0.1 is there, which it isn't. Then you try to insert '127.0.0.1' (including single quotes in the **value**), which is already there, which is why it fails.

Comment: To fix your problem take the single quotes out of the variable definition of $ip, and do one of the following: (1) use a prepared statement for the first query "where ip=?" or (2) write "where ip='$ip'"

Comment: The single quotes contained in the variable were causing the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answered, the question, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score -3):

The IP field in database is a string. Probably in the first sql statement you must use quotes?

```
$db_handle->query("SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE ip = $ip");
```

Replace with:

```
$db_handle->query("SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE ip = '".$ip."'");
```

Comment: yes, sorry: $db_handle->query("SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE ip = '".$ip."'");

Comment: Look at his embedded code and notice 2nd line in his body function :)

Comment: But I think that the problem is the same that I have tried to solve. Explained yet by @juacala

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your time, and helping a noob like me.